# How do I remove the quotation marks off of a string to be used as a variable - python

Tags: python

I am trying to pick a random item from my list and then pick a random item of the dictionary that has the same name as the item in the list.

```py
import random

letters = ["a" , "b" , "c"]

a = {
  "item1": "Q",
  "item2": "W",
}
b = {
  "item1": "E",
  "item2": "R",
}
c = {
  "item1": "T",
  "item2": "Y",
}

item_num = random.randint(0, len(letters)-1)
print(letters[item_num].get([random.randint(0, 1)]))
```

I always get the same error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`, so I'm thinking that this is being caused because `item_num` would = something like `'a'` instead of just `a` without the quotation marks. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't put a b and c into a dict themselves and then grab them by doing `mydict['a']['item1']` or `mydict['c']['item2']`? Because that would be the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get that error is that you're calling `get` on a `str`.

`item_num` is an `int`. You access an element of `letters` with it, which is fine because `letters` is a `list`. However, an element of `letters` is a `str` (`'a'`, `'b'` or `'c'`), which you obviously can't call `get` on.

What you want to do is call `get` on the *dictionary* corresponding to the value of `letters[item_num]` you got. Accordingly, this probably does what you want:

```
import random

letters = ["a" , "b" , "c"]

a = {
  "item1": "Q",
  "item2": "W",
}
b = {
  "item1": "E",
  "item2": "R",
}
c = {
  "item1": "T",
  "item2": "Y",
}

source = random.choice(letters)

print(globals()[source].get(f'item{random.randint(1, 2)}'))
```

That said, it's likely not what you *should* do (programmatic access of global variables). Instead, you can consider:

- Using a nested dictionary, where `['a', 'b', 'c']` are the keys
- Not requiring additional processing of the random integer to get to the second-level keys (`1`, `2` as keys instead of `'item1'`, `'item2'`)

Example:

```
data = {'a': {1: 'Q',
              2: 'W'}
        ...}
```

Comment: Another thing OP could do is just eliminate dictionaries altogether and make a list of lists like:
`list_tups = [["Q","W"],["E","R"],["T","Y"]]` and just do `x = list_tups[random.randint(0,2)][random.randint(0,1)]` or slightly more complex `random.choice(random.choice(list_tups))`

Comment: @NickVitha True; depends on OP's use-case. Given the liberal use of `randint`, I would say that that's currently the better solution, but you never know.

Comment: @gdms yeah personally I agree with your nested dict answer the most.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a global scope you can use `globals()` or eval the letter::

also for picking a random item from a dict, you need to know the keys and then pick a random one:

```py
item_num = random.randint(0, len(letters)-1)
rand_key = random.choice(["item1", "item2"]) 
print(globals()[letters[item_num]].get(rand_key))
```

```py
item_num = random.randint(0, len(letters)-1)
rand_key = random.choice(["item1", "item2"]) 
print(eval(letters[item_num]).get(rand_key))
```

Comment: I tried both of these and they both come back with the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: that's because `get()` for dicts receives a key, in this case `"item1"` or `"item2"` and you are passing a list with a random int in `.get([random.randint(0, 1)])`

Comment: i edited it so you can see how to pick a random key